# Entity Framework - dynamic query

Tags: entity-framework, expression

I'm creating a dynamic expression builder and trying to implement the 'like' function. Before writing my own I've searched for any existing function and found one close to my need. After several experiments I couldn't bring it to run for types other than string.

When I pass a parameter of type `int` then I get this error:

> Method 'System.String ToString()' declared on type 'System.String' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Int32'

My code looks like this:

```
private static MethodCallExpression GetLowerCasePropertyAccess(MemberExpression propertyAccess)
{
    //return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(propertyAccess, "ToString", new Type[0]), typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[0]));
    return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(propertyAccess, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes)), typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
}

private static readonly MethodInfo ContainsMethod = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(String) });

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create<T>(string propertyName, ComparisonOperators comparisonOperator, dynamic comparedValue1, dynamic comparedValue2 = null)
{
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName));
    ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(comparedValue1, comparedValue1.GetType());
    Expression expressionBody = null;

    switch (comparisonOperator)
    {
        ...

        case ComparisonOperators.Contains:
            //var indexOf = Expression.Call(memberExpression, "IndexOf", null, Expression.Constant(comparedValue1, typeof(string)), Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            //expressionBody = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(indexOf, Expression.Constant(0));
            expressionBody = Expression.Call(GetLowerCasePropertyAccess(memberExpression), ContainsMethod, Expression.Constant(comparedValue1.ToLower()));
            break;
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expressionBody, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing, but I think your error is caused by this line:

```
return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(propertyAccess, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes)), typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
```

Which will always try and call the `ToString` method for a `string` type, so if you try and use an `Int32` property, you're then trying to call `String.ToString()`, since the implementation of `ToString()` will be different for different types and the two implementations will not necessarily be compatible, you'll get the exception you're seeing:

```
Method 'System.String ToString()' declared on type 'System.String' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Int32'
```

From what it looks like you're doing, I think this may be what you're after:

```
return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(propertyAccess, propertyAccess.Type.GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes)), typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
```

Which will use the correct implementation of `ToString` (with type obtained from `propertyAccess.Type`).

Comment: I've tried your solution but now i get a new error: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to entities doesn't support `.ToString` method. For converting numeric values to string you need to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` method. I've fixed your code and now you can do `like` on string and numeric columns:

```
private static Expression GetConvertToStringExpression(Expression e)
{
    // if property string - no cast needed
    // else - use SqlFunction.StringConvert(double?) or SqlFunction.StringConvert(decimal?);
    Expression strExpression = null;
    if (e.Type == typeof(string))
        strExpression = e;

    var systemType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(e.Type) ?? e.Type;

    if (systemType == typeof(int) 
        || systemType == typeof(long) 
        || systemType == typeof(double)
        || systemType == typeof(short)
        || systemType == typeof(byte)) // continue
    {
        // cast int to double
        var doubleExpr = Expression.Convert(e, typeof (double?));
        strExpression = Expression.Call(StringConvertMethodDouble, doubleExpr);
    }

    if (systemType == typeof (decimal))
    {
        // call decimal version of StringConvert method
        // cast to nullable decimal
        var decimalExpr = Expression.Convert(e, typeof (decimal?));
        strExpression = Expression.Call(StringConvertMethodDecimal, decimalExpr);
    }

    return strExpression;
}

private static MethodCallExpression GetLowerCasePropertyAccess(Expression propertyAccess)
{
    var stringExpression = GetConvertToStringExpression(propertyAccess);
    if (stringExpression == null)
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Not supported property type {0}", propertyAccess.Type));

    return Expression.Call(stringExpression,
        typeof (string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes));
}

private static readonly MethodInfo StringConvertMethodDouble = typeof (SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert",
    new Type[] {typeof (double?)});
private static readonly MethodInfo StringConvertMethodDecimal = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert",
    new Type[] { typeof(decimal?) });
```

Comment: Hi Sorry but I have to remove the mark answer. I still get an error while testing. Somehow the function 'GetConvertToStringExpression' still doesn't work. The error i'm getting: 'int has no definition for ToLower'

Answer (score 0):

I have just made something like that:

```
    public Expression<Func<T,bool>> BuildContainsExpression<T>(MemberExpression memberExp, object comparedValue)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(memberExp.Member.DeclaringType, "x");
        var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", types: new[] { typeof(string) });

        var comparison = Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Call(
                        method: method,
                        instance: memberExp,
                        arguments: Expression.Constant(comparedValue)),
                    Expression.Constant(true)
            );

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
    }
```

And it builds an expression like below:
`x.Language.Contains("tr")` 
(with my dynamic parameters)
[image: Sample Expression]